# UIPageviewcontroller swipe page not working

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a basic `UIPageViewController` in my apps after login. However, I would to modify the paging and set the initial viewcontroller as the middle one(page A) [image: like this]

After login it could only show the initial but the paging is not working. How can i solve this problem? Please leave a comment if you need anymore information.

```
class MainPageViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {


var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
let pages = ["SecondVC","MainVC","ThirdVC"]


//MARK: Page view controller datasource

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
    viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        if let index = pages.indexOf(viewController.restorationIdentifier!){
            if index > 0 {
                return viewControllerAtIndex(index - 1 )
            }
        }

        return nil
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
    viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        if let index = pages.indexOf(viewController.restorationIdentifier!){

            if index < pages.count - 1 {
                return viewControllerAtIndex(index + 1)
            }
        }
        return nil
}

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UIViewController?{
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(pages[index])
    return vc
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StructurePageViewController"){
        self.addChildViewController(vc)
        self.view.addSubview(vc.view)

        pageViewController = vc as! UIPageViewController
        pageViewController.dataSource = self
        pageViewController.delegate = self

        pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewControllerAtIndex(0)!], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil )
        pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you see and what you expect to see.

Comment: It appears you deleted the initialization code which is probably part of the problem.

Comment: It can only showed one page (the orange page) but the swiping is not working.

Comment: Debug and / or make some print statements in your methods. Are they called? What happens when they're called? Print some warning or fail when viewControllerAtIndex returns nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your source code you have the line

```
 pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewControllerAtIndex(0)!], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil )
```

Which selects the left page to start (Index 0). Try

```
 pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewControllerAtIndex(1)!], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil )
```

to start at Index 1 = middle page = page A.

Comment: pageViewController.setViewControllers([detailViewControllerAt(index: 1)!], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil )