# iOS Swift UIPageViewController not responding to swipe

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have this very wierd issue. I have simple implementation for page view controller in a project. However the pageview controller is not responding to swipe, or rather sometimes it attempts to swipe but stops(without ujpdating) again like its hanging, which is really weird to me. I have search SO for answers non of them seem to address my issue. Kindly assist me on this. Many thank. See code below i have used

```
  class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {


lazy var controllers: [UIViewController] = {
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Onboarding", bundle: nil)

    let vc1 =  sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RedVC")
    let vc2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PurpleVC")

    return [vc1, vc2]

}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.dataSource = self

    if let firstVC = controllers.first {
        self.setViewControllers([firstVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}


func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let vcIndex = controllers.index(of: viewController) else { return nil }
    let previousIndex = vcIndex - 1
    guard previousIndex >= 0 else { return nil }
    guard controllers.count > previousIndex else { return nil }
    return controllers[previousIndex]
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let vcIndex = controllers.index(of: viewController) else { return nil }

    let nextIndex = vcIndex + 1

    guard controllers.count != nextIndex else { return nil }

    guard controllers.count > nextIndex else { return nil }

    return controllers[nextIndex]
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you hitting any API's in respective view controllers?

Comment: No am hitting any api at all @DharmeshKheni

Comment: If this is a simple project than can you share demo of this?

Comment: Actually the project is for production, when the actual implementation was not working. I had to create another storyboard within the app/project to test, with the above code. So am afraid I my not be able to share the project source. I hope you understand @DharmeshKheni

Comment: @DharmeshKheni do you have any ideas why UIPageViewController will not respond to swip? Kindly advise please

Comment: I have created a demo with your code and for me its working fine. Take a look: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=70857810141539717402

Comment: @DharmeshKheni does it mean that, something else is blocking the swiping in my project. What might that be. this is so wierd.

Comment: is there any code you would like to show from other 2 view controllers?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I can see that is is working. I have also tried now to create another demo project just like you have done and it is also working. however on my main project same code is not working.

Comment: Without seeing other code nobody can help.

Comment: There are no codes in the other 2 view controllers.

Comment: ok then I can say something is wrong in other controller which is affecting this view controller.

Comment: DO you have ideas of what that might be?

Comment: Sorry no idea about that.

Comment: Wow! I appreciate the time you have taken to assist so far on this. This issue is just so weir and eratic

Comment: is it okay to go say like a skype call with you so you see the issue, i could share screen with. Please confirm if it is okay @DharmeshKheni

Comment: yes sure you can add me as dharmesh.kheni.root

Comment: you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963970/uipageviewcontroller-swipe-page-not-working I hope it will solve you issue.